# IE to read return key as onchange event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

Here is my example; type something in the field and press return.  In FF and Chrome, this is read as an onChange event and executes the alert(), whereas IE (and I believe Opera) don't.

Is there a fix for this?  It's very annoying.

http://jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/p5vwA/

Answer (score 0):

A complete form with a submit button [behaves as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/p5vwA/1/).  If you need to force the issue, you can do something ridiculous like `onkeyup="this.onchange();"`

Comment: Or create then hide a submit button?  Surely onkeyup will submit each time I change anything?

Comment: That doesn't work anyway.  You're getting the form value, not the input value.

Comment: @jdborg No clue what you are talking about.  It works fine.  Why would you have a textbox without a form anyway?

Comment: Because I don't want to submit anything.  JS reads the value of the input.

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed by using jQuery .change()